# Is the recurrent background wind musical theme in The Mandalorian (2019) played with a bes'bev?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

According to Star Wars Fandom:

> A bes'bev was a traditional Mandalorian flute. Forged from beskar iron, a bes'bev was a combination of musical instrument and melee weapon. At one end, a bes'bev was cut to a sharp tip, similar to a quill stylus, and this bladed end made the instrument ideal for stabbing and drawing blood. A bes'bev was also hard and sturdy, and could be hefted as a club should the need arise.

Probably it is a bit early but I am  intrigued to know if the recurrent background wind musical theme played in The Mandalorian (2019) is performed (within the Star Wars Universe) with a bes'bev?

[The Mandalorian - Soundtrack [Theme Song]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7yqW64Dx7c)

Comment: It’d be helpful if you defined what a bes‘bev is.

Comment: I don't understand the question, especially the "within the Star Wars Universe" mention. Is the theme park supposed to be intradiegetic? In the video, it sounds like any TV show's theme song.

Comment: Out of universe, the instrument doesn't exist. In universe, the song probably doesn't exist.

Comment: the instrument doesn't exist in-universe either at this time @DJSpicyDeluxe since it's a Legends thing and not Disney canon

Comment: @NKCampbell Which I suppose furthers the argument. Either in universe or out of universe, this question really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

## No

Out universe, the composer was [Interviewed by Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/disney-plus-the-mandalorian-music-score-explained-by-composer-2019-11) some time recently and says that he used [recorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recorder_(musical_instrument)) run through distortion.  I wouldn't say the sound is very distorted: the instrument(s) definitely sound like some kind of [fipple flute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fipple).

## Probably Not

In universe, given that the bes'bev is a melée flute, it seems obvious that it would be used to play music in universe. The problem is that the background soundtrack isn't actually part of the action taking place. The various motives and themes that the composer devises are for the benefit of the audience as aural clues.

If you don't see anyone playing a bes'bev on screen -- even a background character playing in a street scene -- chances are good any music you're hearing is out universe background music intended to support the on screen action.

Comment: This is all out of universe, which is not what the question asks for.

Comment: But the music is out of universe, how would it be played with an in universe instrument? It's not like the 'jizz' of tatooine or something where the track featured in the cantina and the characters could hear it.

Comment: @WraithLeader -- Well, you can buy a bes'bev and play the music out world on an in world instrument if you like. From what I can tell, it's basically a whistle with a sharp point on the end. Just be sure to stick the right end into your mouth before playing! (No guarantees on the musicality on the products sold on Etsy, etc.)

Comment: @elemtilas I saw this question pop up yesterday and thought it was more recent. FWIW I am trying to say I think you answered the question correctly and succinctly so you got my +1. I am trying to understand the top comments position about it being out of universe when the song doesn't exist in universe so clearly, no this isn't played in universe on a melee flute because it isn't played on anything.

Comment: @WraithLeader -- Ah, understood!  Exactly. Well I didn't respond to Stormblessed before because, quite simply, the comment makes no sense. Yes, my response refers to out of universe music. And, so what? The OP's query explicitly refers to out of universe music!! Even quotes the soundtrack wherein the fictional instrument is represented by the recorder.